# Nuxt build is failing because of Sentry

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, sentry

My Sentry instance went down temporarily, and I noticed it caused my Nuxt build to fail. Output from Bitbucket pipelines:

```
  ERROR in Sentry CLI Plugin: Command failed: node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli releases new 4.1.0
  error: API request failed
  caused by: sentry reported an error: gateway timeout (http status: 504)
```

In my `nuxt.config.js`, I have

```
sentry: {
    dsn: "<dsn>",
    disabled: isDevelopmentMode,
    config: {
      environment: process.env.ENV,
      release: process.env.npm_package_version,
      autoSessionTracking: false
    },
    publishRelease: isDevelopmentMode ? false : {
      authToken: process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
      url: '<url>',
      org: '<org>',
      project: '<project>',
      release: process.env.npm_package_version,
      include: [`things`],
      ignore: ['node_modules']
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to prevent this error from failing the build?